# LEFT JOIN for two diferent values

Tags: mysql

tab_city

```
 id_city   city
  1       Paris
  2       Texas
  3       Toquio
```

tab_control

```
id_control origin  destination
 1             1           3
```

In the case of previous tables I need to get the data from tab_control and the corresponding cities from tab_city.

If it is only origin is quite simple:

```
SELECT origin.tco, city.tci
FROM tab_control tco
LEFT JOIN tab_city tci ON tco.origin = tci.id_city
```

return

```
origin = 1
city = Paris
```

However, I need to get

```
origin = 1
city = Paris
destination = 3
city_destination?? = Toquio
```

Comment: Just join to it twice, giving each reference a different alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another `JOIN` for the destination

```
SELECT tco.origin, tci.city, tco.destination, d.city
FROM tab_control tco
LEFT JOIN tab_city tci ON tco.origin = tci.id_city
LEFT JOIN tab_city d ON tco.destination = d.id_city
```

Comment: Thanks Uueerdo and Eric. Works great.I do not have enough reputation to vote